# ReactiveUI assign ViewModel fields in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I'm making an application in WPF with ReactiveUI. I have a UserControl with a view model that has a property called `Title`, which is a string. How can I assign that property in XAML in the MainWindow view?

Comment: Set the datacontext to the view model then use wpf binding

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a public property of the current `DataContext` using the `{Binding}` markup extension in XAML regardless of whether you're using ReactiveUI or not:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

ReactiveUI does also provide a way to bind to properties *programmatically*:

```
public YourControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
    {   
        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Title, v => v.textBlock1.Text)
            .DisposeWith(disposables);
    });
}
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/) for more informatiom.